# Define function to find the last even digit using recursion

Tags: c++

Suppose input no is f(354683257) returns 2.

Comment: Easy. 3 = 03. And 0 is even. So it returns 1.

Comment: @MSalters - going by your reasoning, the answer would have to be '0', as per the example the program should print the digit, not it's position.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you can break this into two easier problems.

- How do you find the last digit of a given number?
- How do you strip off the last digit of a given number?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. However, what are you supposed to do if there are no even digits in the number?

```
int findLastEvenDigit(int n)
{
   lastDigit = n % 10;
   if (lastDigit % 2 == 0) return lastDigit;
   else return findLastEvenDigit(n/10);
}
```

Assumptions: No negative numbers (not sure/relevant if it will work for them)

Comment: @user710360 - how is this recursive?

Comment: Completely missed that part. There ya go.